# Document general project Multiroom-Multimedia with multiple Questions/Self-Answers?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic

But this may result in that there are also some questions that do not natively belong to Raspberry Pi. The context is that the answers are needed for the general project. The idea is to have a general question/answer that describes the project and briefly its parts and refer to the detailed questions, bundled with a tag **Multiroom-Multimedia**.

For example if I define to have Kerberos identification for single sign on to simplify room walking then a proper question is [Howto install DLNA media renderer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/79004/79866) but [How to setup SASL Proxy Authorization with an OpenLDAP server on Debian](https://serverfault.com/q/993553/458473) is also needed and running on a RasPi of the project but more a general problem.

I'm working on this project at my home and would like to share it with the community. I would like to have it all together on **raspberrypi** as one (big) project that is ideal made with Raspberry Pis and to benefit from the community here.

What do you think? Is this acceptable? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a great idea as long as you break it into appropriate sized chunks, which it sounds like you intend to do.  This could also include a "master Q&A" pitched on a higher level of abstraction that refers to various component tasks in other Q&As.

With regard to topicality, as I and others have noted here before, our overlap with U&L, SO, and EE is such that if we were very vehement about it, the site would not be feasible because there would not be enough "non-gray" area left. We are hardly the only SE site that overlaps another, of course, and some sites, rather than rejecting questions that overlap with other sites, encourage it. So the network leaves it up to individual exchanges.

The reason the policy has evolved this way here is because it allows us some room to limit questions, meaning the truly significant issue is not enough people to answer them, or people without the expertise available on other sites. It's a disservice to people in need of such help not to migrate or close as off-topic.<sup>1</sup>

The realm of the self-answered question doesn't suffer this problem, presuming the person who writes them knows what they are talking about and can communicate that knowledge effectively.  From what I have seen of your work, this is not an issue; I believe you know what you don't know and you also are good at research and practical implementation.  You are certainly one of the most valuable contributors here over the past year, and more from you is always welcome by me and I am sure other member of the community would echo that sentiment.

---

1. This discretionary enforcement of course leaves room for unfairness.  I've always been open about my inconsistencies with anyone who cares to ask.  But, although I think it has happened, I honestly cannot recall anyone complaining "If you closed my question as off-topic, why didn't you close this one?".  In general the questions that are closed this way have other problems beside topicality, which is why I usually do not migrate them directly to somewhere else. Conversely, I'd observe that some migrations by other mods on other sites occasionally appear to be intentional off-loading of just plain junk.

Comment: Thanks for the compliments :-) But I'm unsure about the second link in my question about SASL Proxy Authorization. Standing for itself it really has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi, only in the wider context of a specific project. You can answer it at Raspberry Pi to have it all together on one side or you can leave it at serverfault.com. People looking for this problem doesn't expect to find it at Raspberry Pi, so I tend to leave it there. But then you only have a reference to it with the "master Q&A" and cannot tag it with the "project tag". I would like to select the tag and have all Q&As.

Comment: Unless you move/copy the post from serverfault, there's no way to do that AFAIA.  However, you could use the "learn more" tag page to link it; whoever follows the idea is pretty likely to look at that.  There may be a complication WRT other people using the tag, that would have to be sorted out case by case.

Comment: You can make a "glue" Q&A just containing a short description with the link and the project tag.

Comment: Sounds good to me.  This is possibly something we could do more generally.  Did you run across the idea somewhere?

Comment: No, idea just coming to me as I read your comment.